# Symfony2 - Rendering a subclass attribute of an object referenced to as a superclass instance

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, inheritance

Here is the issue I have been dealing with all day...

I have got a superclass called `Message` :

```
class Message
{   

protected $id;

protected $body;

protected $sender;

protected $receiver;

// [...]
```

from which inherits my class `Bill` :

```
class Bill extends Message
{
protected $id;

protected $amount;
```

And I wanted to create a Dialogue class that gathers several messages (for instance bills) :

```
class Dialogue
{
protected $id;

protected $subject;

protected $messages = array();
```

And here is the corresponding mapping (YAML, Mongodb) :

```
Bundle\Document\Dialogue:
repositoryClass: Bundle\Repository\DialogueRepository
fields:
    id:
        id:  true
    subject:
        type: string
referenceMany:
    messages:
        targetDocument: Message
        cascade: [remove]
```

The problem is, when I try to render some attributes specific to Bill (for instance, in Twig : `dialogue[0].messages.amount`), I get this error :

> Method "amount" for object "MongoDBODMProxies__CG__\Bundle\Document\Message" does not exist.

I think I have understood that my bill is considered as a Message, and not a Bill... Furthermore, I don't think it is possible tu typecast, in PHP, in order to make sure that `dialogue.message[0]` is considered as a Bill... What can I do to access these specific attributes ?

Help :(

PS : I may have a hint : this error occurs when I load dialogues objects from the corresponding repository. However, if I create a new Dialogue and a new Bill in a controller and render them directly, everything works correctly.

So I tried a $get_class($bill) before and after persisting a Bill object, and that is what I got back :

- before persisting : Bundle\Document\Bill
- after persisting + loading from the repo : MongoDBODMProxies__CG__\Bundle\Document\Message

My issue could come from here, don't you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a design issue - your `Dialogue` holds a collection of `Messages`, which do not anything about being subclassed or not.

Either you provide all your `Message` types with a common `Interface`, that has all the accessible properties you need, either you explicitly provide your `Dialogue` entity with a separate relation for every type of `Message` you want to assign to it, e.g.:

```
Bundle\Document\Dialogue:
...
referenceMany:
    messages:
        targetDocument: Message
        cascade: [remove]
    bills:
        targetDocument: Bill
        cascade: [remove]
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had thought about that.
However, this is really frustrating as before persisting and querying, everything works just fine !... And I wanted to have a messages[] attribute where I could put different Message subclasses... 
So it is sure there is nothing else to do ? It has nothing to do with Doctrine hydration ?

Comment: @Moncef [Check this](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/07/20/mixing-types-of-documents.html), though I am not fond of the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had already spent hours on that, you've just made my day :) :) :)
Finally, I removed the optional field "targetDocument" from dialogue.mongodb.yml to mix documents... And it seems working !! :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dialogue[0].messages[0].amount
```

As messages is an array, but you try to access it as an object, or

```
{% for message in dialogue[0].messages %}
    {{ message.amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately it still throws the same error... :(

Comment: I have added a PS to my first post, with what could be a clue...
Fingers crossed